# Instantiate image in rails 3.1 app then upload to S3 with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm creating a barcode .png in a callback using the [Barby gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/barby):

Isbn.rb:

```
before_save :barcode

def barcode
   barcode = Barby::Bookland.new(self.productidentifier_idvalue)
   my_bc = Barcodeimg.new(:isbn_id => self.id)
   my_bc.image = File.open("#{self.productidentifier_idvalue}-barcode.png", 'w')  do |f|
    f.write barcode.to_png
  end
   my_bc.save!
end
```

Then I'm hoping to upload it directly to S3 via paperclip: here's the Barcodeimg.rb model:

```
  require 'open-uri'
  require "aws/s3"
class Barcodeimg < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_attached_file :image,

                 :storage => :s3,
                 :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                 :s3_protocol => "https",
                 :path => ":class/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
                 :bucket => "bucketname",
                 :url  => ":s3_eu_url"
end
```

I know the credentials work as I'm using the exact same settings in another model. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? A new Barcodeimg instance is being saved, but without the attachment. There are no error messages - just no image appearing on S3! From the stack trace:

```
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "barcodeimgs" ( "created_at", "image_content_type", "image_file_name", "image_file_size", "image_remote_url", "isbn_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ["created_at", Tue, 30 Aug 2011 20:26:20 UTC +00:00], ["image_content_type", nil], ["image_file_name", nil], ["image_file_size", nil], ["image_remote_url", nil], ["isbn_id", 7128], ["updated_at", Tue, 30 Aug 2011 20:26:20 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File.open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000069) will return the result of the block. Which means you're writing the length of the file to your attachment.

I would replace the block with:

```
f = File.open("#{self.productidentifier_idvalue}-barcode.png", 'w+')
f.write barcode.to_png
my_bc.image = f
```

Another problem could be the permissions of the current directory. Do you have the rights to write there?

Comment: Hiya - thanks for the thought. An error came back: ActionView::Template::Error (not opened for reading). Perhaps that's the permissions problem that you suggest.

Comment: No, that's me writing code when I should sleep ;-) . The `File` should be opened with `w+`.

Comment: How would you do this without first writing to disk? Heroku wont let you write "locally" at all. :-/

Comment: @MatthewClark [it will](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), but you have to be on the latest stack (Cedar).

Comment: ah, seems to be a permissions issue with S3 not heroku. Thanks!

Comment: this is the error I'm getting:  [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/barcode20121113-2-tb9utn.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>

Comment: ended up fixing it by streaming the file via strio